# A conjecture about the prime function $p_n$: $p_m \cdot p_n >p_{m \cdot n}$

Tags: prime-numbers, computational-mathematics, conjectures

While testing my system [Zet](http://forthmath.blogspot.se) for computational mathematics I find possible relations now and then. The latest is:

Conjecture:

> For all $(m,n)\in\mathbb Z_+^2$ except $(3,4),(4,3) \text{ and } (4,4)$ it
>   holds that $p_m\cdot p_n > p_{m\cdot n}$

Comment: Since $p_n\approx{n}\ln{n}$ it should be pretty easy to prove.

Comment: Better yet, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem#Approximations_for_the_nth_prime_number), the bounds are $n(\ln{n}+\ln\ln{n}-1)<p_n<n(\ln{n}+\ln\ln{n})$.

Comment: That's right. Follows immediately even from your first consideration. If I were the OP, I'd give you the bounty.

Comment: @YiannisGalidakis, prove it and earn 75p.

Comment: Prove it using somebody else's idea? No. That's not fair to barak manos. Ask him to prove it if he wants or prove it yourself. Cheers.

Comment: Another fantastic question.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Both the methods represent a partial proof of the conjecture. For a complete proof see **Winther's** answer below.

### **First Method**

We know that, $$\dfrac{x}{\ln x}<\pi(x)<\dfrac{2x}{\ln x}\tag{1}$$

for all $x\ge 17$ (see Greg Martin's comment below).

We prove the following theorem,

> **Theorem.** For all $x,y\in \mathbb{N}$ and $x,y\ge 24154953$ we have $\pi(xy)>\pi(x)\pi(y)$ where $\pi(x)$ denotes the prime counting function.
>
> *Sketch of the proof.* If we can show that, \begin{align}\dfrac{xy}{\ln xy}>\dfrac{4xy}{(\ln x)(\ln y)}&\implies \dfrac{(\ln x)(\ln y)}{\ln xy}>\dfrac{1}{4}\\&\implies\dfrac{(\ln x)(\ln y)}{(\ln x+\ln y)}>\dfrac{1}{4}\tag{2}\end{align}Then we are done. Let us now  suppose that $a=\ln x$ and $b=\ln y$. Then, we are to show that for all sufficiently large $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$ we have, $$\dfrac{4 ab}{a+b}>1\implies 4>\dfrac{1}{a}+\dfrac{1}{b}\tag{3}$$ Then if we take $a\ge 17(=\max(4, C))$, we have $(3)$. This in turn shows that for all $x,y\ge e^{17}$ we have $(2)$. Since $24154953>e^{17}$, we are done.

When we have this theorem, what we need to do is to choose both $p_n$ and $p_m$  such that $p_n,p_m\ge e^{17}$. Then we can say that, $$\pi(p_mp_n)>\pi(p_m)\pi(p_n)\implies \pi(p_mp_n)>mn\implies \pi(p_mp_n)>\pi(p_{mn})\implies p_mp_n>p_{mn}$$All that remains is to check the remaining cases.

### Remarks

We have proved that $\pi(xy)>\pi(x)\pi(y)$ for all sufficiently large $x,y\in\mathbb{N}$. But now we pose the question that for which functions $f:D\to \mathbb{N}$ with $\mathbb{N}\subseteq D\subseteq \mathbb{R}$ we can say that $\pi(f(xy))>\pi(f(x))\pi(f(y))$?

Examining the proof carefully we can find a sufficient condition for such $f$'s.

- Since $(1)$ is always valid for $x\ge \max(2,C)$, if we take $f(x)\ge \max(2,C)$ for all $x\in \mathbb{N}$, $(1)$ will hold for our case too.
- Observe that we have written, $$\dfrac{xy}{\ln xy}>\dfrac{4xy}{(\ln x)(\ln y)}\implies \dfrac{(\ln x)(\ln y)}{\ln xy}>\dfrac{1}{4}$$To satisfy this requirement we take $f(xy)\ge f(x)f(y)$

Furthermore observe that any function satisfying these two requirements also satisfies $(3)$ because, $$\dfrac{1}{\ln f(x)}+\dfrac{1}{\ln f(y)}\le \dfrac{1}{\ln 2}+\dfrac{1}{\ln 2}=\dfrac{2}{\ln 2}<4$$

Hence the complete statement of the theorem can be written as,

> Let $f:D\to \mathbb{N}$ (where $\mathbb{N} \subseteq D\subseteq \mathbb{R}$),
>
> - $f(x)\ge 2$ for all $x\in \mathbb{N}$
> - $f(xy)\ge f(x)f(y)$
>
> Then $\pi(f(xy))>\pi(f(x))\pi(f(y))$ for all $f(x),f(y)\ge e^{17}$.

But the bound obtained here is a pretty large bound. To remove this obstacle, we prove the conjecture by following method.

### Second Method

We know that for all $n\ge 6$ we have, $$n\ln n<p_n<2n\ln n\tag{4}$$Hence to prove the conjecture we first need to show that for all $m,n\ge 6$, $$2mn\ln (mn)\le mn(\ln m)(\ln n)$$Which is equivalent to showing that, $$2\ln (mn)\le (\ln m)(\ln n)\tag{5}$$Now let $a=\ln m$ and $b=\ln n$. Then observe that $(5)$ holds for $\min(a,b)\ge 4$ because, $$2(a+b)\le 4\max(a,b)\le \min(a,b)\max(a,b)=ab$$Hence we conclude that for all $m,n\ge 55$ (because $e^4<55$) we have $p_mp_n>p_{mn}$.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime-counting_function#Inequalities

Comment: @GregMartin: Thanks, I was looking for that.

Answer (score 4):

The proof of the conjecture for sufficiently large $n,m$ has been given in the other answer. I will here focus on getting control on the "sufficiently large" part thereby giving a way to make a proof of the conjecture for all $n,m$. I will stick to simply presenting the inequalities and the range for which they are satisfied without showing all the hairy calculations so you should try to verify these for yourself.

---

For $n\geq 6$ [Rosser's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem#Approximations_for_the_nth_prime_number) gives precice inequalities for the $n$'th prime number
$$\log(n) + \log\log(n) - 1 < \frac{p_n}{n} < \log(n) + \log\log(n)$$
From this we get $[\log(n) +\log\log(n)-1][\log(m)+\log\log(m)-1] < \frac{p_np_m}{nm}$ and $\frac{p_{nm}}{nm} < \log(nm) + \log\log(nm)$ so the conjecture follows if we can prove

$$\log(nm) + \log\log(nm) < [\log(n) +\log\log(n)-1][\log(m)+\log\log(m)-1]$$

This inequality can be shown to hold for all $n,m\geq 15$. The cases $n,m<15$ can be done by brute force and shows only three cases where it's violated: $(3,4),(4,3)$ and $(4,4)$. The remaining cases follows if we can prove

$$\log(mn) + \log\log(mn) < \frac{p_m}{m}[\log(n) + \log\log(n)-1]$$

for $m=1,2,3,\ldots,14$ for $n\geq 15$. This inequality can again be shown to hold for $n\geq 33$. A final brute-force check of the cases $n\in[15,33]$ and $m\in[1,14]$ completes the proof of the conjecture.

---

Note that one does not need to prove the best possible version of the inequalities above (i.e. $15$ for the first inequality and $33$ for the second inequality). We can strick with a worse value at the expence of checking more cases numerically. Replacing $15$ and $33$ by $100$ and $1000$ should make the proof of the inequalities easier and it will still be fast to verify the remaining cases $(n \leq 100, m \leq 1000)$ numerically.

Comment: I see now that I was wrong. You are right. For the present moment I think we can't avoid using stronger results.

Comment: @user170039 Ok. Well if you find a better way then let me know. The current way to prove it is a bit clumpsy in my opinion so it would be nice to see if there is a better/simpler way.